# What is the answer for the question 23 and 22 in the image below?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, geometry, letter-sequence

[image]

Source- NTSE Chattisgarh 2015. Sorry, didn't know I cannot post Exam questions.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  If this puzzle is not your own creation, please make sure you attribute the source.  If this is from a test or ongoing competition, then Puzzling is probably not the place for it.  Please visit our [help centre](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) and review [the criteria for on-topic questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to help determine whether your question is appropriate for this site.  Happy puzzling!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include your question in plain text as well as just an image. That 30-character limit is there for a reason, you know ;-) Also, as @GentlePurpleRain has said, you should **provide a source** for where your image came from. You might also like to put your two puzzles into separate questions so that they can more easily be solved individually.

Comment: arent the answers checked off for ye already?

Answer (score 4):

Question 22 - Possible approach

> There seems to be a pattern when you represent the letters as their ordinal position in the English alphabet. In the series given, they alternate positive and negative shifts in the ordinal positions, and the magnitude of each shift decreases by a constant value.
>  
>  `1. FNHLJ = 6, 14, 8, 12, 10 (+8, -6, +4, -2)`
>  `2. WOUQS = 23, 15, 21, 17, 19 (-8, +6, -4, +2)`
>  `3. BNEKH = 2, 14, 5, 11, 8 (+12, -9, +6, -3)`
>  `4. ?????`
>  `5. DTHPL = 4, 20, 8, 16, 12 (+16, -12, +8, -4)`
>  
>  
>  Then we look at the four possible answers:
>  `A) NBKEH = 14, 2, 11, 5, 8 (-12, +9, -6, +3)`
>  `B) NVPTR = 14, 22, 16, 20, 18 (+8, -6, +4, -2)`
>  `C) NFLHJ = 14, 6, 12, 8, 10 (-8, +6, -4, +2)`
>  `D) NDRZV = 14, 4, 18, 26, 22 (-10, +14, +8, -4)`
>  
>  NDRZV does not follow the pattern, so we can eliminate it as the missing word.
>  Note that the first shift in each word seems to alternate; the first shifts of each word are +8, -8, +12, ???, and +16. Maybe we should deduce from this that the 4th word should begin with a negative shift. In other words, we are looking for `(-4x, +3x, -2x, +x)`, for some `x`. That eliminates NVPTR because it begins with a positive shift.
>  The remaining possibilities are NBKEH and NFLHJ, and I don't know what to do from there. Maybe both of them are acceptable.

Question 23 - Just count them!

> [image: triangles]
>  
>  There are 20 possible triangles in total.

Comment: I would go for the first one on 22 because of the underlying series (+8, -8, +12, (-12), +16).

Answer (score 2):

One idea : 
if we rearrange the letters :

FNHLJ => FHJLN there is a gap of 2 letters between each letter

WOUQS => OQSUW there is a gap of 2 letters between each letter

BNEKH => BEHKN there is a gap of 3 letters between each letter

NBKEH => BEHKN there is a gap of 3 letters between each letter

DTHPL => DHLPT there is a gap of 4 letters between each letter

So, the answer is 1) I think. :)

And we cannot see the Q21 ^^